# Groovy usage of named arguments

Tags: groovy

I have a groovy method like this

```
def createMyObj(id,instanceId,isValid) {

   def myObj = new SomeObj()
   myObj.setId(id)
   myObj.setInstanceId(instanceId)
   myObj.isValid(isValid)

   myObj

}
```

I have tests around this when I explicitly do this in the test it works perfectly fine.

```
def testObj = createMyObj(10,20,true)
```

when I tried to use named arguments like this.

```
def testObj = createMyObj(id:10,instanceId:20,isValid:true)
```

it's giving me this exception

```
 No signature of method:createMyObj is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values [[id:10, instanceId:20,..]]
```

I went to this [page](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Extended+Guide+to+Method+Signatures) to understand the concept a little further and I saw this piece of snippet.

In case of `def foo(T t, p1, p2, ..., pn)` all named arguments will be in t, but that also means that you can not make a method call where you access pi by name. Example

```
def foo(x,y){}
foo(x:1,y:2)
```

This code will fail at runtime, because the method foo expects two arguments, but the map you gave is only one argument.

I am not sure if it's the cause of the error I am facing. If it expects two arguments like it says what is the argument that i am missing or how do I pass the second argument?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Calling the function with named arguments like this:

```
def testObj = createMyObj(id:10,instanceId:20,isValid:true)
```

means you're passing just one parameter,`[id:10,instanceId:20,isValid:true]` which is a `LinkedHashMap`, to the function.

Obviously, createMyObj(id, instanceId, isValid) requires 3 parameters. So it's ok that you get this exception:

```
No signature of method:createMyObj is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values [[id:10, instanceId:20,..]]
```

For the latter case:

```
def foo(x,y){}
foo(x:1,y:2)
```

In order to pass a second parameter, you just need to add one more parameter on invoke, like this:

```
def foo(x,y){}
foo(x:1,y:2,"newParameter")
```

In this case `foo` gets

- `x` as `[x:1, y:2]` (which is a `LinkedHashMap`)
- `y` as `"newParameter"`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.so how do i fix this so i can use named arguments? i also don't understand what you mean that its okay to get this exception :)

Comment: nvm got it working. tweaked the function to just take a map and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Yes, if you change function parameter to Map, [] or Object... in definition, it works.