# Custom function in Delcarative Pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have this simple pipeline (I'm using a more complex but this one reproduces it):

```
def test(String name) {
    println test
}

pipeline {
    agent {
        dockerfile {
            label "jenkins-lnx-slave3"
            args "--user root:root"
            dir "CICD"
        }
    }

    stages {
        stage ('Test') {
            steps {
                test(name: 'Hello')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And Jenkins is giving me this "No Such DSL method 'test' found" error:

```
> [Pipeline] } [Pipeline] // withEnv [Pipeline] } [Pipeline] // node
> [Pipeline] End of Pipeline java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL
> method 'test' found among steps [ArtifactoryGradleBuild,
```

This goes on and on for many lines. Am I doing the custom function correctly?

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to call `test` with a named argument and that's causing the breakage. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16725801/9498358) explains what's happening when you try to use named params in groovy.

Additionally, you have a typo inside `test`:
`println test` should be `println name`.

Comment: Didn't know about the named parameter stuff. Thank you.